# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' while trying to fix my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take all columns with a '%' and removing the '%,' turning the string into a float, and dividing by 100, then turning it into a decimal.

I created a list of all the columns that I want to do that to with:

```
percentages = (df.filter(like='%').columns)
perclist = percentages.tolist()
```

Then I run this code but it won't work:

```
df[perclist] = df[perclist].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
```

Comment: Apart from the regex-based solution below (though I think it needs `"%*$"` to mimic `rstrip`), a slight change to your code is via `apply`. Since `perclist` is a Python list, `df[perclist]` is a dataframe which doesn't have a `.str` accessor. But a Series does so you can apply your code to each column as `df[perclist] = df[perclist].apply(lambda col: col.str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0)`.

Comment: Also, for your possible future queries, please share a [mcve]. Thanks and welcome to the website.

Answer (score 1):

`str.rstrip` is for `Series` not `DataFrame`.

```
df[perclist] = df[perclist].replace('%$', '', regex=True).astype('float') / 100.0
```

**Tip**: avoid to create a useless subset of your dataframe:

Replace:

```
percentages = (df.filter(like='%').columns)
perclist = percentages.tolist()
```

By:

```
perclist = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('%')]
```